# pyqt5でAxe3Dを使ったときに、マウスでの視点変更やスケール変更がうまく行かない

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

pyqt5でAxe3Dを使って3dプロットをしたいです。Axe3Dで書いたグラフでは左クリックしながらドラッグで視点変更、右クリックしながら上下のドラッグでスケール変更が出来ます。ここで、グラフのキャンバスに機能を追加しようと思い、キャンバスを別クラスで記述しようとしました。その際、Axes3Dに本来ついていたマウスドラックでの視点やスケール変更の機能が失われてしまいました。下のGUIでは左側のキャンバスではマウスドラッグの機能が残っていますが、右のグラフではその機能は失われてしまい、ドラッグしても反応は有りませんでした。何がいけなかったのでしょうか。matplotlibのバージョンは3.1.3です。

---

**表示されるGUI**
[image: 画像]

**ソースコード**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor

class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    #def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        width=6
        height=6
        dpi=100

        self.color="#ffffff"
        
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        #self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))

        self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setFixedSize(600,450)
        
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.win=parent 
        super(MyStaticMplCanvas,self).__init__(parent)
        #self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        #self.setAcceptDrops(True) 
        self.win2=super(MyStaticMplCanvas,self)


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))        
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.axes = Axes3D(self.figure)
        self.plot()
        
        self.canvas2 = MyStaticMplCanvas(self)
        self.plot2()       

        layout1=QHBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout1.addWidget(self.canvas2)
        self.setLayout(layout1)

        self.show()
        
    def plot(self):
        x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        y = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        Z = np.sin(X)+ np.cos(Y)
        
        self.axes.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='jet')
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes.set_zlabel("z")
        
        self.canvas.draw()
        
    def plot2(self):
        x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        y = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        Z = np.sin(X)+ np.cos(Y)
        
        self.canvas2.axes.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='jet')
        self.canvas2.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.canvas2.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.canvas2.axes.set_zlabel("z")
        
        self.canvas2.draw()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: 2つの領域を同等の構成や条件で作っていないからでは？ Qtではなくmatplotlibだけの描画ですが、こちらの記事 [mplot3d.Axes3D – 3次元グラフの概要](http://taustation.com/mplot3d-axes3d-overview/) の下2つでは両方の領域を同じやり方で作成していますよ。

Comment: 質問が分かりにくくてすみません。キャンバスの記述を別クラスに分けた際に動作が変わってしまうことが質問の主題です。画像右側のcanvas2でもドラッグでの動作を残すためにはどのようにコードを直せばよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 別クラス化してやりたいことは何か、それは別クラスにしなければ出来ないことか、を問い直してみては？ 別クラスで`canvas2`を作るのではなく、紹介先のように例えば`self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(121, projection="3d")`と`self.axes2 = self.figure.add_subplot(122, projection="3d")`で領域を増やして、canvas2関連は削って、`plot2()`で`self.axes2.Xxxx()`で描画すれば両方を同じように動かすことが出来ます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。最終的にキャンバスごとに独自のホイールや左右のクリックでの挙動、コンテキストメニューの表示などを行いたいので、キャンバスごとに別クラスで記述した方が見やすくもなるので、質問させていただきました。ですので、キャンバスを別クラスで記述したく思っています。どのように修正すればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

後々どうなるかわかりませんが、今は取り敢えず以下部分の変更で、両方のグラフが操作できるようになります。

- `class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):`の中で、`self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig)`の処理を`canvas`関連処理の後(現在は`self.setParent(parent)`の後)に移動する。

`class Main(QDialog):`の中で最初のグラフ用の処理が`canvas`→`Axes3D`の順になっていたので合わせてみました。

```
class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    #def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        width=6
        height=6
        dpi=100

        self.color="#ffffff"
        
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        #self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))

        #### self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig) # ここでは行わない
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setFixedSize(600,450)
        
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig) #### こちらに移動する
```

Comment: お陰様で無事動作することが出来ました。質問を読み返してみたら、我ながら分かりにくい文章で申し訳ないです...。